# Maps in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get a simple map as my mainActivity to test how maps with compose works. Unfortunately I just fail at the beginning with an Errormessage which says basically nothing but "IllegalStateException".
I've tried to extract the map code from the original Google example here:
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Crane
I've tried to rebuild a simple Composable, made an API Key at Google Cloud Platform and added it to my manifest.

Thats the `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
package com.veloce.mapstesting

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.annotation.FloatRange
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.maps.android.ktx.addMarker
import com.google.maps.android.ktx.awaitMap
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
            MapViewContainer(mapView)
        }
    }
}

const val InitialZoom = 5f
const val MinZoom = 2f
const val MaxZoom = 20f

@Composable
fun MapViewContainer(map: MapView) {
    val cameraPosition = remember {
        LatLng(48.2050491798, 16.3701485194)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(map) {
        val googleMap = map.awaitMap()
        googleMap.addMarker { position(cameraPosition) }
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cameraPosition))
    }

    var zoom by rememberSaveable(map) { mutableStateOf(InitialZoom) }
    ZoomControls(zoom) {
        zoom = it.coerceIn(MinZoom, MaxZoom)
    }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    AndroidView({ map }) { mapView ->
        val mapZoom = zoom
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val googleMap = mapView.awaitMap()
            googleMap.setZoom(mapZoom)
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cameraPosition))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ZoomControls(
    zoom: Float,
    onZoomChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        ZoomButton("-", onClick = { onZoomChanged(zoom * 0.8f) })
        ZoomButton("+", onClick = { onZoomChanged(zoom * 1.2f) })
    }
}

@Composable
fun ZoomButton(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        ),
        onClick = onClick
    ) {
        Text(text = text, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
    }
}

fun GoogleMap.setZoom(
    @FloatRange(from = MinZoom.toDouble(), to = MaxZoom.toDouble()) zoom: Float
) {
    resetMinMaxZoomPreference()
    setMinZoomPreference(zoom)
    setMaxZoomPreference(zoom)
}
```

And these are the `MapUtils`:

```kotlin
package com.veloce.mapstesting

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply { id = R.id.map }
    }

    val lifecycleObserver = rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose { lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver) }
    }
    return mapView
}


private fun rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
    LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: "I just fail at the beginning with an Errormessage which says basically nothing but "IllegalStateException" " -- it is still a good idea to include the stack trace in your question. While the details may not help you directly, they might help those who wish to try to help you with the question. FWIW, https://piotrprus.medium.com/display-map-snapshot-using-jetpack-compose-e3222186a1a5 may give you some ideas.

Comment: Consider adding your vote to this bug tracker issue to facilitate Google Maps usage with Compose: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198126189

Comment: Interesting IMPL for your composable ... I've never seen a function instance that has a return type before.  I'll have to give that a try myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are reading this, but you have forgotten to include ON_START event for lifecycle, so you are throwing the exception. Also you are calling onStart on ON_CREATE.

Also consider populating the lifecycleObserver to be scoped into the DisposableEffect and make the DisposableEffect also aware of the mapView (give it as an argument).

Answer (score 1):

Official Google Maps library for Jetpack Compose came out recently, check it out:

> [Google Maps Compose](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose)